# JQuery get data attributes from element in table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Suppose that i have a table that is populated with a razor `@foreach` loop.

For each row, I have a delete button, which looks something like this:

```
.....
<tr>
    <div style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; margin-left:5px" id="deleteEntity" data-Id="@Student.Id" data-Name="@Student.Name" data-Age="@Student.Age">                
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
        <span style="color:#bfbfbf">Delete</span>
    </div>
</tr>
```

I want to have a jQuery function, that is capable of fetching the data attributes from my `#deleteEntity` div. Therefore I have done something along the lines of this:

```
$('#deleteEntity').on("click", function (event) {

    var button = $(event.target);
    var Id = button.data('Id')
    var Name = button.data('Name')
    var Age = button.data('Age')
    debugger;
});
```

However based on what I have done above, all of my values are `Undefined`.

- Therefore, how do I correct this, so that I get the values that are specific to this delete button in my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the button from `$(this)` inside the handler.  *However*, you're re-using the same `id` on every button so the behavior of the click handler is essentially undefined.  You'll want to use a `class` instead.

Additionally, the name for a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) must not contain capital letters.  So simply make them lowercase.

For example:

```js
$('.deleteEntity').on("click", function (event) {
    var button = $(this);
    var id = button.data('id');
    var name = button.data('name');
    var age = button.data('age');
    console.log(id);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(age);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; margin-left:5px" class="deleteEntity" data-id="@Student.Id" data-name="@Student.Name" data-age="@Student.Age">                
    <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
    <span style="color:#bfbfbf">Delete</span>
</div>
```